# Find time zone from date time

Tags: php, timezone

I have a string like
`Sat, 27 Oct 2012 23:47:57 -0700` and I want to get corresponding timezone of `-0700` like `PST` ,`UTC` etc..

Comment: There might be more than one timezone identifier for a given offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fundamentally, you can't. You've currently just got an *offset* from UTC... and that could map to multiple time zones. You could create a fixed-offset time zone, of course - but that's not the same thing as "the time zone the user was originally in when this date/time value was generated" which is what I suspect you want.

You could see step through *every* time zone and see whether it's valid in each one - but you'll need to be careful due to some times which are ambiguous. For example, on Sunday in the UK, both "Sun, 28 Oct 2012 01:30:00 +0100" and "Sun, 28 Oct 2012 01:30:00 +0000" would have been valid. You probably want to work out the absolute UTC instant, and check what the offset for that instant would have been in the candidate time zone. If that offset is the same as the one you started with, that time zone is *one* of the ones which fits.

Quite what you'll want to do if you find multiple time zones which fit, I don't know - we don't really have enough context to give advice.

Comment: How often would there be more than one TimeZone that would match the given UTC+Offset?

Comment: @JohnGietzen: Very often indeed. Less so if you're not interested in *historical* changes (i.e. given the UTC offset at a particular instant, if you only care about UTC offsets later than that) - but it still happens, and more than you might expect. As just one example, consider London and Casablanca - *most* of the time they have the same offset, but for one month in the middle of summer, Casablanca goes back to standard time. (May be for Ramadan - not sure yet.)